# Google Cloud Platform Computed Engine instance experienced DDoS attack

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have experienced DDoS attack in GCP.
I did something to a new project.
I want to know is this normal?

1. Enable ssh root + password to login server.

   I did something like https://mapgun.com/archives/2235
2. Install Mongodb.

   apt-get update && apt-install mongodb
3. Open port

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8InN.png)

4. Close and did nothing. Didn't open any http server.

I don't know much of DDoS attack.
Is that possible to getting DDoS attack?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUXJV.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to get a DDoS attack in Google Cloud Platform. This can be self-inflicted as well as attacks from outside. The good thing about these problems is that they usually have known solutions. I would suggest following [this guideline](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/11/how-to-avoid-a-self-inflicted-DDoS-Attack-CRE-life-lessons.html) to avoid self-inflicted DDoS attacks.

It is also highly recommended to follow the best practices for DDoS protection and mitigation on Google Cloud Platform which are available [in this document](https://cloud.google.com/files/GCPDDoSprotection-04122016.pdf).

If this is **not a DDoS attack**, you can simply block this by controlling [egress traffic](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#egress_cases) of GCP Firewall.